# Bounded measurable function is a uniform limit of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that if $f : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to [0, \infty]$ is a bounded unsigned measurable function if and only if $f$ is the uniform limit of bounded simple functions.

I know how to do this if $f$ has a finite domain, but for the whole $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, I can not divide it into some finite number of closed subspaces.

I saw there is a proof:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounded_Measurable_Function_Uniform_Limit_of_Simple_Functions

But I am pretty sure there must be some much simpler way to do it, any hint is appreciated!

Comment: This is actually very simply, just dressed up in precise language. The proof is basically a picture of essentially Riemann sums. See Folland's Real Analysis proposition 2.12 for details. He gives a picture proof along with the formal proof.

Comment: If it's bounded, why do you include $\infty$ in the codomain?

Comment: It just indicate that $f$ is nonnegative, nothing else, $f$ is still bounded.

Comment: @Moya I have Folland's second edition: it's proposition 2.10 there.